# Как избежать выгорания usb портов на "малинке"?

Tags: arduino, usb, raspberry-pi, электроника

Я делал проект, где малинка через usb управляла ардуинкой, а ардуинка, в свою очередь, получая данные через ком порты управляла драйвером двигателя l298n. Изначально все было хорошо, все исправно работало и в том случае, когда питание ардуинки шло из распбери пи и в том случае, когда ардуинка питалась отдельно. Но при очередном включении usb порты малинки просто перестали работать(конкретно на том включении, ардуино питалась от распбери пи). Как лучше питать ардуино, чтоб избежать выгорания портов(от малинаи или отдельно). Как в принципе избежать их выгорания(не используя гальваническую развязку)?

Comment: А защитные диоды у вас стоят в цепи двигателя? Или двигатель двунаправленый нельзя поставить? Можно все выводы ардуино подпереть стабилитронами на 3 вольта (питание, юсб, управление движком как минимум), плюс в цепь от выводов по которым может прийти "обратка" от двигателя поставить "ограничительные" резисторы от 10 до 200 ом (они ограничат бросок тока от двигателя).

Comment: Защита строится 1- стабилитрон (паралельно цепи). 2 - резистор 10 ом -200 ом - в разрыв цепей которые надо защитить. Чем больше - тем лучше, но после определенного порога - схема перестанет работать.  3. Конденсатор (на землю). В цепях конденсатор возьмет на себя бросок напряжения раньше чем откроется стабилитрон. В зависимости от частоты подбирается номинал конденсатора. Где высокая - ставят пикофарады, где низкая (оголо герца) - можно несколько микрофарад, однозначно не могу сказать, чем больше - тем лучше, но при превышении "разрешённого" порога - устройство начнет сбоить.

Comment: Правильная схемотехника это не та вещь, которую Вам посоветуют на форуме программистов. Тем более, если в схеме есть электродвигатель (то есть большая индуктивность со всеми вытекающими в виде переходных процессов с бросками тока-напряжения). Нужна нормальная разработка схемы с анализом всех возможных режимов. Гальваническая развязка тоже не панацея, так как при неправильных режимах будет гореть сама гальваническая развязка.

Comment: @nick_n_a, хм, если это обратка от двигателей, то почему не выгорели драйвер двигателей и ардуинка?

Comment: Чип - набор транзисторов - согласны? Одни более мощные или защищенные, другие менее. "Где тонко - там и рвётся" выгорели более слабые цепи, а более сильные могли пропустить бросок транзитом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Общая схема защиты "отсебятина". Не претендую на лучший ответ, дам общие рекомендации.

Цепи USB скорее всего уже защищены (обычно в их защите нет конденсаторов, лучше добавить), но лучше проверить (то можно и ПК спалить порты). Цепи к двигателю нужно поставить защитные цепочки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вместо резисторов - можно перемычки.
R1 - может отсутствовать. R1 и R2 от 10ом  до 200 ом.

Цепь R2-V1 - это "стабилизатор". Если извесно напряжение броска (например двигатель 12 вольт даст бросок 12 вольт) то по закону ома - можно получить ток через резистор - соответственно ток через стабилитрон. Согласно этого тока - можно посчитать мощность стабилитрона и резистора. При броске напряжения открывается стабилитрон - и лишнее напряжение идет "на землю". Т.к. стабилитрон может открыться не сразу - то кратковременный бросок можно компенсировать другими элементами (R1, С1, С2).

Так как у ардуино уровни от 0 до 3 вольт - то стабилитрон на 3 вольта, проверить напряжение можно вольтметром. Если в даной цепи другие напряжения - то нужен другой стабилитрон с напряжением максимума допустимого.

R1 и R2 - чем больше - тем лучше, но при превышении "нужного" значения, у вас будет "обрыв" сигнала. Для USB цепи - R2 - 56 Ом (ссылка ниже).

Разряженый конденсатор забирает бросок напряжения раньше чем сработает стабилитрон, для того, что бы зарядится. Чем больше конденсатор - тем лучше, но после определенного значения схема начнёт не правильно работать (двигатель будет работать дольше чем нужно после снятия сигнала, например, USB-сигнал перестанет проходить)
С1 - выбирается в зависимости от рабочей частоты. Если частота низкая - выбирается порядка 0.1 ... 5 микрофарад, и если присутствуют высокие частоты - то ещё ставят С2 порядка нескольких пикофарад - что б гасить высокочастотную составляющую сигнала. Для высокой частоты ставят несколько пикофарад.

Если у вас высокочастотные броски - то желательно что бы не было "висячих" ног. Лучше защитить все цепи от чипа (кроме ног которые заземлены или запитаны).

В цепи питания - обязательно должен присутствовать стабилитрон или чип стабилизации (обычно он есть на плате ардуино).

Рекомендую посмотреть на цепи защиты на примерах

https://habr.com/ru/post/128939/ (D1 D2 R3 R4 - защита)

http://old.symmetron.ru/suppliers/wurth/usb-protection.shtml Защита USB